# How to represent List of Objects field in a model with ORMLite?

Tags: java, android, database-design, orm, ormlite

I am trying to use ORMLite to represent **comments** in a **conversation**, like this:

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "comments")
public class Comment implements Parcelable{

    @DatabaseField(id = true)
    private Long id;
    @DatabaseField
    private Long conversation_id;
    @DatabaseField
    private String text;
    ...

    public static class List extends ArrayList<Comment>{
    }
}
```

...and...

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "conversations")
public class Conversation implements Parcelable{

    @DatabaseField(id = true)
    private Long id;
    ...
    @ForeignCollectionField
    private Comment.List comments;
    @DatabaseField
    private Date created_at;
    ...
}
```

And I am getting this error:

> Field class for 'comments' must be of class ForeignCollection or
>   Collection

I am also using GSON so these models are populated automatically from json. For example:

```
{
    "created_at":"2013-08-12T20:38:11Z",
    "id":31,
    "comments":[
        {
            "conversation_id":31,
            "id":46,
            "text":"IE sucks",
        },
        {
            "conversation_id":31,
            "id":47,
            "text":"Yes it does",
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this just by changing descriptors?
Is it necessary to rework the Conversation class to use ForeignCollection as a type for comments or change Comment.List class to extend ForeignCollection? I'd like to avoid doing any of those because I am afraid it would break GSON implementation which currently works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Comment class:

```
...
@DatabaseField(
    foreign = true
)
private Conversation conversation_id;
...
```

The conversation_id will actually only store id of the Conversation object, not the object itself.

There is a really good (if somehow unformatted) documentation here: http://ormlite.com/docs/foreign-object